# Is it possible to use computer camera from windows phone emulator 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am very newbie to the windows phone development. I try to come up with a simple app taking photos. For testing I need to run emulator and take photos from the emulator by using computer camera. However, if I start to camera it shows very interesting shapes and does not use computer camera. Is there any way to exploit PC camera directly from emulator and take photos?

Answer (score 5):

No way to do this, you just get the "interesting shapes" and that is it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it currently isn't possible to use a webcam or other built in PC camera to use with the camera on a Windows Phone emulator.