# windows 8.1 phone emulators camera not working

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8.1, emulation

I am trying to use the camera on the windows 8.1 emulator (Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB), but I cannot get it to work (see below image). After some searching I have not been able to find someone who has had the same issue (maybe its a real simple solution that i'm missing or i'm searching the wrong keywords).

I have looked through the phones (emulators) settings, searched several keywords. I have tried to open different emulator options but they all fail (I think that is down to available ram in my machine). I have confirmed that it is not down to anything in my app by accessing from the camera button on the side.

To get Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB working I had to follow the work around found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2911380). Could this be the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, it is a feature. There is no way to make the emulator show images from a computer camera, see [Is it possible to use computer camera from windows phone emulator 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342267/is-it-possible-to-use-computer-camera-from-windows-phone-emulator-8-1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that has saved me hours of finding workarounds. I would be interested to know why though?

Comment: No idea, maybe it was difficult to implement, you have to ask Microsoft